# Multiple text inputting Shiny

Tags: shiny

I wonder there is no Gadgets is available in shiny for inputting text (pasting multiple values) as like this.. Any suggestions ?

[image]

Comment: You can take in a comma separated input and in the server side, split the input by comma and continue with your work.

Comment: `textAreaInput` looks just like this.